# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'password' on MySQL query to select user by email

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a MySQL query in a class method that should return one user's data given an email input:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_by_email(cls,data):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %(email)s;'
        return connectToMySQL('pet_log').query_db(query,data)
```

And then I call this function in my userroutes.py to use bcrypt to check if the password matches on the login input:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['post'])
def login():
    data = {'email':request.form['email']}
    user_in_db = User.get_by_email(data)
    if not user_in_db:
        flash('Email does not have an associated account.', 'login')
        return redirect('/')
    if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_in_db.password, request.form['password']):
        flash('Invalid email/password combination.', 'login')
        return redirect('/')
```

I keep getting this an error on `if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_in_db.password, request.form['password']):` stating that AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'password'.  But when I use `print(user_in_db)` there is definitely a password attribute.  I have used almost this exact code in other websites and it has worked every time, so I have no idea why its not working.

Is my query the wrong object type?

Here is the terminal output from printing user_in_db (I deleted the hashed password cause felt weird sharing even a hash):
{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Eric', 'last_name': 'Fallon', 'email': 'ericmfal@gmail.com', 'password': '#hashedpassword', 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 18, 5, 57), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 8, 18, 5, 57)}

I have tried manipulating the type of object I got back from the query but it didn't work

Comment: `get_by_email()` returns a dict, which indeed does not have a `password` attribute.  It has a password **key**, which is similar but is accessed in a different way.  Try `user_in_db['password']` instead of `user_in_db.password`.

Comment: This worked! I had to also add the index [0] to user_in_db but switching it to a key access worked, thank you!